# org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, ear

I have created enterprise project in eclipse . dynamic web project and ejb project has reference for enterprise project.
When i running admin(enterprise project) run as selecting wildfly server 18.I am getting below error.
Can anyone tell what i am missing .

```
20:09:48,376 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Admin.ear"."Admin-web.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Admin.ear"."Admin-web.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "Admin-web.war" of deployment "Admin.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:183)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:663)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:248)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:156)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:176)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Try this [answer](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/automation/discussion/can-not-deploy-kie-server-because-of-service-jbossejbdefault-resource-adapter-name-service-not-found)
 ./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml

Answer (score 8):

I found that I was not setting the resource-adapter-name. I resolved this by updating my standalone.xml and adding the below `<mdb>` element inside `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:6.0">`

```
<mdb>
    <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:hornetq.rar}"/>
    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
</mdb>
```

In my case the resource-adapter-name is hornetq.rar